# (Swift Playground Template) Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a Swift Playground Template (Xcode 11.1) downloaded from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Swift%20Playgrounds%20Author%20Template). While compiling, it told me:

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3 compiler
```

I am using Xcode 11.3.1. Should I upgrade to the newest version or downgrade to some specific versions? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlaygroundSupport` is compiled with Swift 5.1(integrated with Xcode11.1) and it would not be compiled with the newer version of Xcode.

For the most compatibility, you may download [Xcode11.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and run this template using Xcode11.1 as well.